# Using templates in std::conditional to determine function argument types

Tags: c++, oop, c++11, vector, constants

I want all my saving and loading of data to go through the same functions to reduce the chance of bugs. To do this I used a lot of templates (and much function overloading). It worked, my code is now much cleaner, but I was unable to use `const` for saving (because it goes through the same functions as the loader does, where the data is kept non-const).

I'd like to use the `const` correctly, so here is an attempt to get a simple version working, where the data (in this case `std::vector`) is non-const for `std::ifstream`, and `const` otherwise:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

template <class Foo>
void Overload(const Foo & foo)
{
    std::cout << "went to const" << std::endl;
}

template <class Foo>
void Overload(Foo & foo)
{
    std::cout << "went to non-const" << std::endl;
}

template <class StreamType, typename... Arguments>
void ReadOrWrite (

    /* for 1st argument */ StreamType & filestream,

    /* type for 2nd argument */ typename std::conditional< 
        /* if */    std::is_same<StreamType, std::ifstream>::value,
            /* then */  std::vector<Arguments...>,
            /* else */  const std::vector <Arguments...>
            >::type

        /*2nd argument name */ & vector
        )
{
    Overload(vector);
}

int main ()
{
    std::ofstream output_filestream;
    std::ifstream intput_filestream;

    std::vector<int> vector;

    ReadOrWrite(output_filestream, vector);
    ReadOrWrite(intput_filestream, vector);

    return 0;
}
```

I know that it will compile/run properly if I edit the function calls to this:

```
ReadOrWrite<std::ofstream, int>(output_filestream, vector);
ReadOrWrite<std::ifstream, int>(intput_filestream, vector);
```

But I don't want the user of the function to need to list the types during the function call.

Is there a clean way to do what I'm suggesting?

**EDIT**

There appears to be a question over the legitimacy of my motive.

I did not explain my motive thoroughly because it's not overly simple (neither is it overly complicated) and I respect the readers' time.

The example I gave was the bare component of what I haven't been able to solve - and the "overload" functions were just included to see if it worked.

However it appears that my lack of explanation has caused confusion, so I will expound:

I have made a small library to handle the general-case saving and loading of data. It successfully allows the users' classes to have simple save/load methods by using the following interface:

```
class SomeClass
{
public:

    template <class StreamType>
    void SaveOrLoad(StreamType & filestream)
    {
        saveload::SaveToOrLoadFromFile(filestream,

            data_1_,
            data_2_,
            /* ..., */
            data_n_,
        );
    }

    void SaveToFile (const std::string & filename)
    {
        std::ofstream output_filestream(filename, std::ios::binary);

        // file handling

        SaveOrLoad(output_filestream);
    }

    void LoadFromFile (const std::string & filename)
    {
        std::ifstream input_filestream(ptf::problem_input_file, std::ios::binary);

        // file handling

        SaveOrLoad(input_filestream);
    }
};
```

This library handles all fundamental data types, STL containers, and any other containers which use the correct `SaveOrLoad(StreamType &)` interface, including saving and resizing of all containers. The library has forced all saves and loads to go through the same deterministic functions, and hence has completely removed the potential for bugs involving of a save/load mismatch (unless the user misuses the library's simple interface).

The problem that I have with my library - and hence the reason for my question - is a theoretical one because I have no need for it presently: The `SaveToFile` method should be able to be `const`.

Comment: As it stands, the stuff inside `std::conditional` is a non-deduced context, which is why `Arguments` won't be deduced for you. I would add another level in between: A function that takes just `T` as second argument and, depending on whether `T` is `const`, calls separate `ReadOrWrite` functions (well, `Read` and `Write`). In C++11 that's a bit more cumbersome than the `constexpr` we have in newer versions, but doable. I'm also seeing big red flags with "I do both reading and writing through the same function" - that's an almost guaranteed violation of the single responsibility principle...

Comment: "... to reduce the chance of bugs. To do this I used a lot of templates". This made me laugh. I think you're actually making a God function: one that can do everything.  [That is considered an anti pattern](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_object)

Comment: Personally I would write separate read and write functions.  They do different things so they should be separate.  That lets you apply `const` in the write function easily.

Comment: I recommend that you take inspiration from the standard library and how it handles containers: By passing iterator pairs instead. That will generally simplify things, and also make your function more flexible to boot (as they can then handle other containers and also partial ranges).

Comment: To be clear, I've used this on a database where large problem instances with nested data types must be saved in exactly the same fashion as they are loaded or you end up with data that has been very badly incorrectly loaded, often resulting in crashes. With long lists of data in each class type it's a very bad design to keep loading and saving separate.

Comment: In that case,  note the existence of libraries like [boost::serialization](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html)

Comment: Thanks JHBonarius, I probably should've done that earlier, but I'm now determined to make this work (see my edit). For nothing else, I'm getting used to using type_traits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, apologies, my explanation of my problem was bad and I'll do better in future.

Just in case anyone happens to read this and have a similar problem, I solved it by introducing two *wrapper* functions whose purpose is to explicitly state the template parameters:

```
template <class DataType>
void ParseData (std::ofstream & output_filestream, const DataType & data)
{
    ReadOrWrite<std::ofstream, DataType> (output_filestream, data);
}

template <class DataType>
void ParseData (std::ifstream & input_filestream, DataType & data)
{
    ReadOrWrite<std::ifstream, DataType> (input_filestream, data);
}
```

The important part is that this solution is scaleable: To handle each new data type I only need to write one `ReadOrWrite` function, with no unnecessary template parameters at function calls.

How the `ParseData` functions fit into the solution:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>


// lots of useful typetraits:
#include <type_traits>

template <class S, class T = void>
struct is_vector : std::false_type {};

template <class S, class T>
struct is_vector <std::vector<S,T>> : std::true_type {};

template <typename Datatype>
inline constexpr bool is_vector_v = is_vector<Datatype>::value;

// Kinda similar format to my serialization library:

template <class Foo>
void Overload(const Foo & foo)
{
    std::cout << "went to const" << std::endl;
}

template <class Foo>
void Overload(Foo & foo)
{
    std::cout << "went to non-const" << std::endl;
}

// Special type trait specific to this library
// (within an anonymous namespace)

template <typename, typename Data>
struct vet_data_constness
     : std::add_const<Data> {};
    
template <typename Data>
struct vet_data_constness <std::ifstream, Data>
  : std::remove_const<Data> {};

template <typename StreamType, typename Data>
using vet_data_constness_t
        = typename vet_data_constness<StreamType,Data>::type;


template <class StreamType, typename DataType>
std::enable_if_t<is_vector_v<DataType>>
ReadOrWrite (StreamType & filestream,
             vet_data_constness_t<StreamType, DataType> & vector)
{
    Overload(vector);
}

// These functions are simply for routing back to the ReadOrWrite
// funtions with explicit calls

template <class DataType>
void ParseData (std::ofstream & output_filestream, const DataType & data)
{
    ReadOrWrite<std::ofstream, DataType> (output_filestream, data);
}

template <class DataType>
void ParseData (std::ifstream & input_filestream, DataType & data)
{
    ReadOrWrite<std::ifstream, DataType> (input_filestream, data);
}

int main ()
{
    std::ofstream output_filestream;
    std::ifstream intput_filestream;

    std::vector<int> vector;

    ParseData(output_filestream, vector);
    ParseData(intput_filestream, vector);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The best suggestion would be to provide two separated functions, since reading and writing are two distinct operations, no matter what type you sent in it. For example, someone could be `fstream` for both input and output. Simply by the type system, you can't know the intent. The decision of reading or writing is usually an intent, and these are rarely embeddable into the type system.

Since saving and loading are distinct operation, it should be distinct functions (possibly sharing code between them)

---

If you really want a function that do both and switch between the types, then I'd suggest constrain the functions for input or output:

```
// output streams
template <class StreamType, typename... Arguments,
    typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<std::ostream, StreamType>::value, int>::type = 0
>
void ReadOrWrite (
    StreamType & filestream,
    std::vector<Arguments...> const& vector
) {
    Overload(vector);
}

// input streams
template <class StreamType, typename... Arguments,
    typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<std::istream, StreamType>::value, int>::type = 0
>
void ReadOrWrite (
    StreamType& inputstream,
    std::vector<Arguments...>& vector
) {
    Overload(vector);
}
```

Since the second is more specialized than the first, it will be taken whenever the stream is `std::istream` and the vector is mutable. Otherwise, the first one is taken.

[Live example](https://godbolt.org/z/JQzrGO)

Comment: Might want to use `std::istream& inputstream` instead of `std::ifstream& filestream`

Comment: @NathanOliver-ReinstateMonica nicely spotted!

Comment: Thanks.  Unfortunately now that I look at it more you'd also need more overloads, or constrain the template as it would be an exact match if something other than an `const istream` is passed.

Comment: To be clear, I've used this on a database where large problem instances with nested data types must be saved in exactly the same fashion as they are loaded or you end up with data that has been very badly incorrectly loaded, often resulting in crashes. With long lists of data in each class type it's a very bad design to keep loading and saving separate.

Comment: @ElliottSmith gathering metadata is another operation. Both saving and loading should use the same metadata, so the same metadata is used in both loading and saving.

Comment: Hi Guillaume, I've provided an update to explain why it's essential that my input stream goes through the exact same functions as the output stream. Through these overloaded functions the data gets reduced to smaller components, eventually reaching "std::is_arithmetic" type, where *finally* they separate into two tiny (one-line) functions where the filestream type is fixed and the data is written in one, or loaded in the other.

Comment: @ElliottSmith interesting, it look like boost::serialization a lot.

Comment: Yeah, that's what JHBonarius was suggesting that I use. When I first searched for a solution to this I just googled for something inbuilt. I didn't come across  boost::serialization. I'll look into it. To be honest, I'm still curious how to get the const into my library.

Comment: @ElliottSmith any reasons why my version wouldn't work?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201677/discussion-between-elliott-smith-and-guillaume-racicot).

Comment: I apologise, I should've asked my question differently. It really needs to be within the one function because this function is used to call many other ReadOrWrite functions, each time reaching a lower level of data (in this case, the elements of the vector), before finally reaching arithmetic data types where there are two overloaded functions which split into std::ifstream / non-const, and std::ofstream / const. Up vote for a good answer. 'Might post a new question with a better explanation of what the problem was.

Answer (score 2):

Another overload solution could transform `ReadOrWrite()`, almost as you have written in your question, in an helper function

```
template <typename ... Args, typename ST>
void ReadOrWrite_helper (ST &, typename std::conditional<
                                  std::is_same<ST, std::ifstream>::value,
                                  std::vector<Args...>,
                                  std::vector<Args...> const>::type vec)
 { Overload(vec); }
```

adding a overloaded couple of `ReadOrWrite()` function to select select the `Args...` and explicit them calling the helper function

```
template <typename ... Ts>
void ReadOrWrite (std::ifstream & is, std::vector<Ts...> & vec)
 { ReadOrWrite_helper<Ts...>(is, vec); }

template <typename ... Ts>
void ReadOrWrite (std::ofstream & is, std::vector<Ts...> const & vec)
 { ReadOrWrite_helper<Ts...>(is, vec); }
```

Observe that, given that the `Args...` types are in non deduced context so are to explicated, I've placed they, in the `ReadOnWrite_helper()` template parameter declaration, **before** `ST`; so there is no need to explicit also `ST`.

Observe also that if you don't need to know the `Args...` types inside `ReadOrWrite_helper()`, all became simpler

```
template <typename V, typename ST>
void ReadOrWrite_helper (ST &, V & vec)
 { Overload(vec); }

template <typename V>
void ReadOrWrite (std::ifstream & is, V & vec)
 { ReadOrWrite_helper(is, vec); }

template <typename V>
void ReadOrWrite (std::ofstream & is, V const & vec)
 { ReadOrWrite_helper(is, vec); }
```

and also disappear the needs of explicating the `V` type.

Comment: I apologise, I should've asked my question differently. It really needs to be within the one function because this function is used to call many other ReadOrWrite functions, each time reaching a lower level of data (in this case, the elements of the vector), before finally reaching arithmetic data types where there are two overloaded functions which split into std::ifstream / non-const, and std::ofstream / const. Up vote for a good answer. 'Might post a new question with a better explanation of what the problem was.